# Type does not satisfy the constraint and incorrectly extends interface when trying to implement generic Specification and Visitor patterns

Tags: typescript, generics, types, visitor-pattern, specification-pattern

I'm trying to implement a generic Specification pattern and a generic Visitor pattern together. Here are my base interfaces.

```
export interface Specification<T, TVisitor extends SpecificationVisitor<TVisitor, T>> {
  accept(visitor: TVisitor): void;
  isSatisfiedBy(candidate: T): boolean;
  and(other: Specification<T, TVisitor>): Specification<T, TVisitor>;
  andNot(other: Specification<T, TVisitor>): Specification<T, TVisitor>;
  or(other: Specification<T, TVisitor>): Specification<T, TVisitor>;
  orNot(other: Specification<T, TVisitor>): Specification<T, TVisitor>;
  not(): Specification<T, TVisitor>;
}

export interface SpecificationVisitor<TVisitor extends SpecificationVisitor<TVisitor, T>, T> {
  visit(specification: AndSpecification<T, TVisitor>): void;
  visit(specification: AndNotSpecification<T, TVisitor>): void;
  visit(specification: OrSpecification<T, TVisitor>): void;
  visit(specification: OrNotSpecification<T, TVisitor>): void;
  visit(specification: NotSpecification<T, TVisitor>): void;
}
```

For convenience, I've implemented some base classes and an abstract class for the basic boolean operators.

```
export abstract class CompositeSpecification<T, TVisitor extends SpecificationVisitor<TVisitor, T>> implements Specification<T, TVisitor> {
  abstract isSatisfiedBy(candidate: T): boolean;
  abstract accept(visitor: TVisitor): void;

  and(other: Specification<T, TVisitor>): Specification<T, TVisitor> {
    return new AndSpecification<T, TVisitor>(this, other);
  }
  andNot(other: Specification<T, TVisitor>): Specification<T, TVisitor> {
    return new AndNotSpecification<T, TVisitor>(this, other);
  }
  or(other: Specification<T, TVisitor>): Specification<T, TVisitor> {
    return new OrSpecification<T, TVisitor>(this, other);
  }
  orNot(other: Specification<T, TVisitor>): Specification<T, TVisitor> {
    return new OrNotSpecification<T, TVisitor>(this, other);
  }
  not(): Specification<T, TVisitor> {
    return new NotSpecification<T, TVisitor>(this);
  }
}

export class AndSpecification<T, TVisitor extends SpecificationVisitor<TVisitor, T>> extends CompositeSpecification<
  T,
  TVisitor
> {
  constructor(readonly left: Specification<T, TVisitor>, readonly right: Specification<T, TVisitor>) {
    super();
  }

  accept(visitor: TVisitor): void {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }

  isSatisfiedBy(candidate: T): boolean {
    return this.left.isSatisfiedBy(candidate) && this.right.isSatisfiedBy(candidate);
  }
}

export class AndNotSpecification<T, TVisitor extends SpecificationVisitor<TVisitor, T>> extends CompositeSpecification<T, TVisitor> {
  constructor(readonly left: Specification<T, TVisitor>, readonly right: Specification<T, TVisitor>) {
    super();
  }

  accept(visitor: TVisitor): void {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }

  isSatisfiedBy(candidate: T): boolean {
    return this.left.isSatisfiedBy(candidate) && !this.right.isSatisfiedBy(candidate);
  }
}

export class OrSpecification<T, TVisitor extends SpecificationVisitor<TVisitor, T>> extends CompositeSpecification<
  T,
  TVisitor
> {
  constructor(readonly left: Specification<T, TVisitor>, readonly right: Specification<T, TVisitor>) {
    super();
  }

  accept(visitor: TVisitor): void {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }

  isSatisfiedBy(candidate: T): boolean {
    return this.left.isSatisfiedBy(candidate) || this.right.isSatisfiedBy(candidate);
  }
}

export class OrNotSpecification<T, TVisitor extends SpecificationVisitor<TVisitor, T>> extends CompositeSpecification<
  T,
  TVisitor
> {
  constructor(readonly left: Specification<T, TVisitor>, readonly right: Specification<T, TVisitor>) {
    super();
  }

  accept(visitor: TVisitor): void {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }

  isSatisfiedBy(candidate: T): boolean {
    return this.left.isSatisfiedBy(candidate) || !this.right.isSatisfiedBy(candidate);
  }
}

export class NotSpecification<T, TVisitor extends SpecificationVisitor<TVisitor, T>> extends CompositeSpecification<
  T,
  TVisitor
> {
  constructor(readonly other: Specification<T, TVisitor>) {
    super();
  }

  accept(visitor: TVisitor): void {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }

  isSatisfiedBy(candidate: T): boolean {
    return !this.other.isSatisfiedBy(candidate);
  }
}
```

All of the above works and compiles without error. But when I run into problems with the compiler when I try to create an interface that extends the base SpecificationVisitor interface and implement a class that extends the abstract CompositeSpecification.

```
export interface NumberComparatorVisitor extends SpecificationVisitor<NumberComparatorVisitor, number> {
  visit(specification: GreaterThan): void;
}

export class GreaterThan extends CompositeSpecification<number, NumberComparatorVisitor> {
  constructor(readonly value: number) {
    super();
  }

  accept(visitor: NumberComparatorVisitor): void {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }

  isSatisfiedBy(candidate: number): boolean {
    return candidate > this.value;
  }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```sh
Type 'NumberComparatorVisitor' does not satisfy the constraint 'SpecificationVisitor<NumberComparatorVisitor, number>'.ts(2344)

Interface 'NumberComparatorVisitor' incorrectly extends interface 'SpecificationVisitor<NumberComparatorVisitor, number>'.
  Types of property 'visit' are incompatible.
    Type '(specification: GreaterThan) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (specification: AndSpecification<number, NumberComparatorVisitor>): void; (specification: AndNotSpecification<number, NumberComparatorVisitor>): void; (specification: OrSpecification<...>): void; (specification: OrNotSpecification<...>): void; (specification: NotSpecification<...>): void; }'.
      Types of parameters 'specification' and 'specification' are incompatible.
        Type 'AndSpecification<number, NumberComparatorVisitor>' is not assignable to type 'GreaterThan'.ts(2430)

Type 'NumberComparatorVisitor' does not satisfy the constraint 'SpecificationVisitor<NumberComparatorVisitor, number>'.
  Types of property 'visit' are incompatible.
    Type '(specification: GreaterThan) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (specification: AndSpecification<number, NumberComparatorVisitor>): void; (specification: AndNotSpecification<number, NumberComparatorVisitor>): void; (specification: OrSpecification<...>): void; (specification: OrNotSpecification<...>): void; (specification: NotSpecification<...>): void; }'.
      Types of parameters 'specification' and 'specification' are incompatible.
        Property 'value' is missing in type 'AndSpecification<number, NumberComparatorVisitor>' but required in type 'GreaterThan'.ts(2344)
```

I don't quite understand why it is complaining. What do I need to change in order to get this to work the way I intend it to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow, there's quite a bit of code in there.  Let's pare this down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which shows the same problem:

```
interface Foo {
  ovld(x: string): number;
  ovld(x: number): boolean;
}

interface BadBar extends Foo {  // error!
  ovld(x: boolean): string;
}
```

Here you have a `Foo` interface with an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) method named `ovld`. This method has two call signatures; one which takes a `string` and another which takes a `number`.  And we attempt to make the `BadBar` interface that extends it.  Our intent is to add a third overload to `ovld` which takes a `boolean`.  But it doesn't work!  Why?

---

The answer is that you cannot simply *add overloads* when you extend interfaces.  Interface extension is *not* [interface *merging*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces).  By redeclaring `ovld` in the extended interface, you are telling the compiler to completely overwrite the type of `ovld` in `Foo` with the version in `BadBar`.  And because the single call signature in `BadBar` is not assignable to the call signatures in `Foo`, that's an error, just like this is an error:

```
interface XXX {
  prop: string;
}
interface YYY extends XXX { // error!
  prop: boolean; 
}
```

In both cases you are extending an interface incorrectly by taking an existing property or method and making an invalid change.  The only acceptable changes are *narrowing* changes, such as changing a `string` to `"a" | "b"`.

---

So, if we can't add an overload merely by re-declaring `ovld()` in `BadBar`, how *can* we do it?  One way is to use an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get the existing call signatures from the parent interface, and then [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with the new call signature:

```
interface GoodBar extends Foo {
  ovld: ((x: boolean) => string) & Foo["ovld"]
} 
/* (property) GoodBar.ovld: ((x: boolean) => string) & {
  (x: string): number;
  (x: number): boolean;
} */
```

The intersection `X & Y` will be seen as a valid narrowing of `X`, so the compiler error goes away.  Furthermore, TypeScript considers the intersection of functions to be equivalent to overloads. And so the above gives you the new `(x: boolean) => string` call signature as the first overload, followed by the existing two overload signatures from `Foo`:

```
declare const goodBar: GoodBar;
goodBar.ovld(false).toUpperCase();
goodBar.ovld("hello").toFixed();
goodBar.ovld(123) === true;
```

Hooray!

---

That means your `NumberComparatorVisitor` might need to be changed to something like this:

```
export interface NumberComparatorVisitor extends
  SpecificationVisitor<NumberComparatorVisitor, number> {
  visit: (
    ((specification: GreaterThan) => void) &
    SpecificationVisitor<NumberComparatorVisitor, number>["visit"]
  );
}
```

If I make that change then the errors go away, because now `NumberComparatorVisitor` really is a valid extension of its parent interface.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZAlsNYQBskG8BYAKBKSQwBcIAnAMwWQDEB7Fgs8pFgNxwBMAFAA8AXEiiUaGAOYBKccACuYAEa0A3J3K8BIxSvU0FSVWxwQQwLcXIBfEpyq0GiJACEQ-TzSQRh1MD8UEis7PjkAPSRfjQ0LDQAhNrcfEJipuaWwCaS0sAyNvaOthTA1PSMSAAatRyl5DDxMOJ5skVIDqXOlW4AmgN+ARBBIbXVBEjRsfFJKU0sLZksFlYaSJxdTuUuVQDibN4gvv6BwaFs9VypAuKC+surOUgAvAB8ElKyckgAZBcsADaACJdPxgQBdTacSIAKiQggWMFolAAnj8DiwjjQAHRgu4PMwrbI-d6ffLyP5XLgPNoFEzKNSaFIPRlGExEp4dOxIWGRErkfgQeA4Y7IeAsYCSJAyQ4+cSY7EdWVYnx4tKCBg4KAQOQ4ygsACqMGRNAAwiAdYI5Mq5cd1XpgQALCA4HAsYF6g1MNDCCBCG2cFXYh1CACMACYAMykl4vJBSJQQGwkLbEUCQWBVJhKN1mrHIIikUr+GAJShlCquZAAZWR8DQdDQ8BAlDQkoAPAAVAA0SC7ADU0FA0AaTsNRkg68LG83W+3gEOR2Pu0vRwk+123h8i9cEIgYJRBDxh+uaOJB6exyYeCw0PwOuRhzX51Am-73KjBC2gvfWxALw5LI1hSKwhBYSgXXPKd61nFs207Xt+zXMc3hMacGybeCF27TcUISN5HyQMCADkIMECCoPEDC4PnRC8KvAj0NgrC6OAXDkMYmhCJSBIKMg2hqJYucEPYpDL2XJihJnVjRI4iSzx4hpuBoMij0owSYJkkScPE-DuOY7TsPozjJO4ojgHIwzMJ0kyFNQ7kBSGMsaArHpqy0mzjMXLjVy4oYzhCGjZIXfS-LMzc3ki6lyBPZdBFgIy2PEABBIJgtssSGLMtDxFve8iLi0cEuE7zUqCNSMu8+T9NypB8ofFIiqPRKvOSpAAHkaCqtiaq4uqGsKq8SqS0TxC6yrSt6vT+pvO9GuU5qRrasakEm0bdOyxS5oK6Fi3IUty2I1Q8gQCsRUtEJ8zAMtlwgHq5JmsyApGc4HtC3z7I3fttwoG6LEgcogqmx6ttQmLjtO+A3KgF82zfNAPy-H9+D-ahAPETlsiIkATqkM7iPgA8j2ahIL30naFtAoJ+KozzaNB0ztuklbNqZ8Hd2uJAaAgSglBoYAkGACAAHckDS-h3rs2rBEg4c+w04wiK6PcKvIxWWYZtmvoMzWQul-qIfIHm+YFoXRfFtXKClrL2YI2WnXl7gBKVlIVa4PiNfp-XbZ1uqbb6nKje53n+cF4Wxa6gOnsUh2ncVwNlPdnRVPVl29cywPme9zOY45lJjdDs2I861PrZB7WZblqAFZdxPrmToWrIz6q84I4OTbD82xfW1mDZyuOoHrrh3bTA7hBc87RSgEIJejsGEheycbbCnXIo+U5XqulgbpYO6A5SXtD-0zgdxSCUpUTaG+J5rxJRwVEkAsOhKBb6aF+4vtb-4e-H+kGQnSvxzq3D+aFg5QCUKaa0ysnLkH3BAQ8x4uLky4pTYOpNcRLWrsPYo+0uDPlfO+bwyMwJowAv2ICxIrAdyLoLauOJn6UBxAQ+GRDPzflIfwf8Pxfj-Hof-QBzDYaEMRsQjhv4uHUBwZ0PanBDquSQBdGelt+C9y1v3M8S83oV0lKvfS68tHb13vvHRvtaoQwvnkJQ18aCCG-r-J+EAX5v0Zn7L+lgf7AAftzNAACgHzztgZcBkDaDQLdrAwmxMkFmRQWZNBnNrgYJxFgx2Q8YF4KfMI1hoj2EozIRjR42QaGmzoakhhTimEsOHGwkhEjuF-H+IkfhvjBFVIRkjcRqNJG6nSbguRE8jpKJCFHUxWcxyGOAWxPRXEDGb0nNdW6o57qjMPj2Y+XFT4WMlFYmxdiPEOMYS4yu-V3F3y8X-Fp-jRltyCQkrgECoHSLHlweBiCMGxLPPEgu9UuLJOGtg9JKQ2k1M6fkihmNgKCzuYXEpCYymMKEXDapOTaldPqQAH3RXC4cOIBGVKycijpeTulPNkSWAZCihmlzUT7MZi85naI2roz6+ifobwnOcBZe8lkH2UkfPlJ9Shn2UpYq+Y49lnO8YcyZrjaqnM8d4vFRyNGoR+NCiQITbGkoyZEhBJNkGBK+cpWKvyUnDm1UCgl7SxHEv-AUrG1D1WdzNvQhFwKUWgpJUgTFSAmllLxYikRRLOHcN6TIvB8ip6XTWhBAJOsJkrxZTMtlEyuUmKZexVZ6yzKbLuaKmg1jxX2POc7Omcbapqu+Q80JFrlKvP1TEw1eV5roNNf81JtbrjuuDXU9G4LCmOu+c6wWfqcWK0DdkntaKpFhueZGysuw3AkUMLQBZxxWwJH0oYlIiazIdmXUyc0O84A0A3TQVlbJaDCsSVeO43z7itXUcABUt8KhdidFYUkHwGo8O+bus8+6V1HpuuuscF6gNvBBM1SEKRh5zopVG5RexX20HfdQhlRjFnUADpemgfYD1GDXaesDhs83bLFTffZJaeC4CTAYQ9lbjUaseYCutRM9XRLPOIAjq7j2gc3ag5t95W1mT+fFAF4SdXdptSGvtuHKFPGKV3W11AkAfHoTRnASZZ2piAA)

Comment: Great explanation, now I understand. The fix is kind of yucky but at least it's something. I might forgo using method overloading and just go with separate distinct methods.